# Ribbon in a Dialog Based Project c++

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, ribbon

I have a MFC project with a nicely toolbar,
but I want to change the toolbar for a ribbon menu

Does anyone knows how can I add the ribbon menu and
use it instead of the menu tool bar?

My project is a Dialog Based Project.

Comment: try this link [Ribbon Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354408.aspx)

Comment: The `CDialog` is a hack to begin with. It's not designed to handle complex UI such as toolbars/menus/panes/ribbons. I would definitely go for a new SDI/MDI project for this (if I had to work with MFC).