# ribbon control in mfc dialog based application

Tags: mfc, dialog, ribbon-control

I am using visual studio 2010 professional edition. I am working on MFC dialog based application.

I have created the ribbon resource and try to load the same using the following:-

```
m_wndRibbonBar.Create(this);
m_wndRibbonBar.LoadFromResource(IDR_RIBBON);
```

Where `CMFCRibbonBar m_wndRibbonBar` is declared in the header file as well.

But I can't create the same in dialog based application, it will work in SDI or MDI application.

I would like to create the ribbon control in a dialog based application.

Is there any possibility to do so, if not, what are the alternatives for the same?

Comment: Several searches with Google will show you that sadly the ribbon will not work with a dialog app framework. Only in SDI and MDI. You are stuck with standard toolbars.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791279/ribbon-in-a-dialog-based-project-c

Comment: See: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e57bdc73-a7f3-4977-897b-feb54b76f91b/ribbon-control-in-mfc-dialog-based-application?forum=vcgeneral

Answer (score 0):

As answered elsewhere on the internet, for example:

[ribbon control in mfc dialog based application](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e57bdc73-a7f3-4977-897b-feb54b76f91b/ribbon-control-in-mfc-dialog-based-application?forum=vcgeneral)

To quote:

> According to the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/ribbon-designer-mfc?view=vs-2019#creating-a-ribbon-by-using-the-ribbon-designer):
>
> Ribbons cannot be created in dialog-based applications. For more information, see see [Application Type, MFC Application Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/application-type-mfc-application-wizard?view=vs-2019).

[image: snapshot]

Possible workarounds:

- To use a Ribbon, use an SDI application with a `View` derived from `CFormView`.
- Use a toolbar instead.